# Create Folder with Numpy Savetxt

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying loop over many arrays and create files stored in different folders.

Is there a way to have np.savetxt creating the folders I need as well?

Thanks

Comment: try ... help(np.savetxt) to get what you can do with numpy function specifics. ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`savetxt` just does a `open(filename, 'w')`.  `filename` can include a directory as part of the path name, but you'll have to first create the directory with something like `os.mkdir`.  In other words, use the standard Python directory and file functions.

Comment: Actually in order to make all intermediate directories if needed the os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True) . If not needed the command will not throw an error.

Answer (score 4):

Actually in order to make all intermediate directories if needed the `os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)` . If not needed the command will not throw an error.